# Docbook <bibliosource> gets lost in the transformation

Tags: xslt, docbook

I have the following structure

```
    <informalfigure xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
      <info>
        <bibliosource>Photo: John Doe</bibliosource>
      </info>
      <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
          <imagedata contentdepth="30mm" contentwidth="35mm" fileref="path/to/img.jpg"/>
        </imageobject>
      </mediaobject>
      <caption>
        <para>Here goes the caption for the image</para>
      </caption>
    </informalfigure>
```

`<imagedata>` and the `<caption>` get rendered but the `<bibliosource>` is gone after the transformation.

I'm using the `docbook-xsl-1.77.0/xhtml/docbook.xsl` for the transformation... I need some guidance on where/how to change the xslt so that `<bibliosource>` gets transformed properly.

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "transformed properly"? How do you want the photo credit to be rendered? For example, if you want it after the caption (or perhaps as part of the caption), you could customize the template matching "caption" in graphics.xsl. (Also, I'd say that `othercredit` is better than `bibliosource` for this kind of metadata.)

Comment: Current xml structure is what it is... not in my hands at all. So I need to have the `bibliosource` transformed. When I say "transformed properly" - I mean anywhere at all :)
After the caption would be great!
I'll have a look at the graphics.xsl - not sure what to change... :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Add the following to your XHTML customization layer:

```
<xsl:template match="d:caption">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="common.html.attributes"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="id.attribute"/>
    <xsl:if test="@align = 'right' or @align = 'left' or @align='center'">
      <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="@align"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </div>
   <div><xsl:value-of select="../d:info/d:bibliosource"/></div>   <!-- This line added -->
</xsl:template>
```

The above works with the [namespace-aware](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ProcesingDb5.html#Db5Xslt) XSLT stylesheets (**docbook-xsl-ns**).

If you use the non-namespace-aware stylesheets (**docbook-xsl**), the corresponding customization becomes:

```
<xsl:template match="caption">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="common.html.attributes"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="id.attribute"/>
    <xsl:if test="@align = 'right' or @align = 'left' or @align='center'">
      <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="@align"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </div>
   <div><xsl:value-of select="../blockinfo/bibliosource"/></div>   <!-- This line added; note blockinfo -->
</xsl:template>
```

The text of the `<bibliosource>` element will appear in a separate `<div>` directly below the caption. The original template is in graphics.xsl.